# Functions similar to Log but with results between 0 and 1

Tags: functions

I need a function similar to Log but it should produce numbers between 0 and 1
Something like:

```
f(0)=0
f(1)=0.1
f(2)=0.15
f(3)=0.17
f(100)=0.8
f(1000)=0.95
f(1000000000)=0.99999999
```

I need this in my program that I am programming and I can use only standard functions like log, exp, etc... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've got a question: f(1000000001)=1 is ok or do you need something like $f(n)_{n \rightarrow \infty}<1$ ?

Comment: $f(x) = 1-\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ ?

Comment: Or take the partial sums $a_1=\frac {1}{2^n}$ or some other geometric series, maybe with a weighing factor.

Comment: "I need this in my program that I am programming" - what exactly are you trying to do that makes you need such a function?

Comment: @J.M. I need to analyze and rate some data but rating should depend on number of previous analysis. So more analysis done => rating more valuable.

Comment: There's a lot of *sigmoidal* functions to choose from: arctangent, hyperbolic tangent, the logistic function...

Comment: Similar to log in what way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sasha's suggestion of $f(x) = 1-\exp(-x)$ is good, but doesn't fit your example values too well, even if you scale $x$ appropriately.  However, some other similar function, such as $f(x) = 1-1/(1+x)$, might work even better.

Comment: In case you're using this, you can generalize the example to $f(x) = x/(a+x)$; this way, you can adjust $a$ to have a slower or faster growing curve.

Comment: How would one scale either of those functions to get the value 1 at some predefined x, say x=100?

Comment: @ed22: Both of these functions will asymptotically approach 1 as $x$ grows but will never reach it, like the OP asked for. Of course, you *could* just define $g(x) = f(x) \mathbin/ f(100)$ so that $g(100) = 1$, with $g(x)$ then approaching an arbitrary asymptote of $1/f(100)$ as $x$ grows further beyond $100$. But depending on how you want $g(x)$ to behave for $x$ between $0$ and $100$, that may not actually do what you want. If you can describe the behavior you want, you could maybe ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 9):

I like the hyperbolic tan (and it likes me) 
$$f(x) = \tanh(x) = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}
 = \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1} = 1 - \frac{2}{e^{2x}+1}$$

$f$ is strictly increasing and satisfies $f'(0) = 1$, $f(0) = 0$, $f(\infty) = 1$.

If you want to map $(-\infty, \infty)$ into $[0, 1)$ (instead of $[0, \infty)$), use 
$$f(x) = \frac{\tanh(x)+1}{2} = 1 - \frac{1}{e^{2x}+1}.$$

I have seen this called the "logistic" curve, or "s-shaped" curve.

Answer (score 8):

If you want it to involve log, try $f(x) = 1 - \log(a)/\log(a+bx)$ for suitable positive numbers $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The beauty of this answer is that you can interpret $\log$ here as either the common or natural one... :D