# Term for functions with results between 0 and 1?

Tags: terminology, monotone-functions

Is there a term for functions $f: x \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to [0, 1] $ that have the following properties:

1. Strictly monotony
2. $f(0) = 0$
3. $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$

Functions (found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57429/functions-similar-to-log-but-with-results-between-0-and-1)) I think about are:

- $f(x)=1−1/exp(−x)$
- $f(x)=1−1/(1+x)$

The reason I'm asking is that I want to search for such functions but don't no what to search for. Therefore as a starting point it would help to know how functions with results between 0 and 1 are called.

**Edit**: as requested in the comments here my motivation *why* I could need functions with such properties. Consider I want to transform the repuation of Stackexchange users into a number between 0 and 1 (a "normalization" which allows me to compare this number) to some other number between 0 and 1 (eg the normalized number of badges). So 0 reputation should be 0; 10 reputation should be 0.1; 1000 reputation should be 0.5, 50K reputation should be 0.9; 1 million repuation should be 0.99, and so forth, but always < 1. If I used $f = log$ this would not bound the values to 1.

Comment: Perhaps a "cumulative distribution function"?  It would help to know *why* you are considering functions with these properties...

Comment: @XanderHenderson, except for property 2 (which is fulfilled by some, but not all), cumulative distribution functions fulfill the properties I mentioned. I'm looking for a a function to give small numbers a small value, and high numbers a high values (with the restriction that the small value should be 0 and the high value below 1) - eg. for some kind of ranking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any accepted term for these functions, but you could use your own suggestion, after a careful warning. Something like:

> For the purpose of this paper, let us introduce a convenient definition. Let us call *normalization function* a function $f: x \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to [0, 1] $ satisfying the following properties:
>
> 1. $f$ is strictly monotone,
> 2. $f(0) = 0$,
> 3. $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. As mentioned in the question, I want to *search*  for such functions (and not to properly name such functions in a paper). However, "normalization function" seems to be a good starting point for my Google search.